# Where can I ask questions like this: "Hi there. Tell me your opinion about my deck"

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering

This community calls itself "board and card games" but refuses to answer a simple question like the one in the title so I'm looking for a site where I can ask something like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: This belongs on meta, if anywhere. There are established guidelines for what types of questions are appropriate for this site, detailed in the FAQ. If you want to discuss things outside the scope of the FAQ, there is a chat system, or you can look for other sites. Criticizing and complaining about this community at the same time as asking for recommendations for other places to go is not particularly constructive, however.

Comment: Come on! I need more downvotes!!!!

Comment: On meta downvotes signify nothing other than disagreement with the post.  There is no reputation at stake on meta, please don't take the down votes personally

Answer (score 6):

From this site's FAQ:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about **_**”, then you should not be
>   asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to
>   explain **_** to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of
>   course welcome in our real time web chat.)

So you could try taking it to web chat.  Alternatively (I assume you're talking about Magic decks) there are a million other community sites out there.  I recommend mtgsalvation.com as one that's busy, friendly and free.

Comment: Friendly what others here cannot be called.

Comment: Well, deck-building advice questions do contain an actual problem someone faces, and they are answerable with good advice. However, the problem is that it would only help the person who asked the question, whereas the goal of Stack Exchange questions are to be more general so more people with the same problem can benefit. It's the same reason why very specific bug-fixing questions on Stack Overflow are either closed or edited to be less localized.

Comment: @edem: I'm sorry to hear you say that. :( Your deck advice questions being closed were not personal! They're just not the kind of questions we're looking to have on this site. If you ever have any other M:TG questions that could be answered with a single authoritative objective answer, the community would be happy to help you out. :)

Comment: @adamjford He's actually asked several questions that seemed pretty good (and got upvoted and received helpful answers).  Good comments, btw!

Comment: @Beofett: Yep, you're right. Should have checked. :P

Answer (score 1):

One way to ask this type of question, which seems to be accepted based on [this discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/585/1583) is to generalize and discuss a strategy and perhaps a particular problem you're having with that strategy against certain other strategies.

If you can make your question general enough it regains that sense of being helpful to others, and does, to some degree, make it a little more time resistant since particular cards will come and go but the effect they provide on game play should still tie into the strategy.

With your particular deck you could explain what your strategy ***is*** and try to strengthen that strategy or ask how a particular change might work with the strategy.

I don't think there's a comprehensive list of strategies out there, but certainly some are obvious: token swarms, white weenie, direct damage, life gaining, aggro decks, mana producing in dual/tri colours and so on ...

Obviously we're all still trying to find that right side of the fine line where these things fit.

For example asking how to modify a white weenie deck so that it can better compete with a red direct damage aggro deck might be better than providing the white weenie decklist and asking for change suggestions.